# Ember.js: property based on promise

Tags: ember.js

Suppose that `company` is a promise defined somewhere in the route. In my controller I defined a computed property `breadcrumb` based on this promise:

```
breadcrumb: function() {
    return [
        ...
        {name: this.get("company").get("name"), url: "#company/" + this.get("company").get("id")},
        ...
    ]
}.property("company")
```

In my template the breadcrumb never update even after the promise resolves.

```
{{format-breadcrumb breadcrumb}}
```

I tried also with `observes` but the result is the same. The only way to obtain the result I want is to observe an attribute of `company`

```
...
}.property("company.id")
```

Is this the only way to create a property based on promises? I would like to observe the promise itself, not one specific attribute...

I'm using ember 1.7 and ember-data beta 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My advice** would be to always depend on the properties you care about:

```
}.property('company.id', 'company.name')
```

since those are the things that can affect the breadcrumb.  If the promise loads and those properties change later, do you want the breadcrumb to be stale (pun unavoidable)

**An alternative** would be to (additionally) observe the promise lifecycle attributes:

- isLoaded
- isSettled
- isRejected
- isFulfilled

So:

```
 }.property('company.isFulfilled')
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html

**Additional thought**, (I) prefer:

```
this.get('company.name')
```

over:

```
this.get('company').get('name')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also for the additional thought! I'm new to Ember and I've a lot to learn